# Curl POST request in JSON format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, http, post, curl

I'd like to send a HTTP POST request in JSON format to a specific URL using Curl in the mac terminal.

1. How do I specify the HTTP verb POST? What is the difference between -d and -X?
2. How do I specify that I'm sending my data in JSON format?
3. Any suggestions on how to test the request itself? I'd like to test and see exactly what JSON data is being sent across before I do my 'live' request. Can I run a Rails server on localhost and send my POST request to localhost? How can I see the JSON data?

Any examples are welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1) If you are using the `-d` option to upload data, curl with automatically use `POST`. The `-X` option is used  when you want  to specify the method (`PUT`, `DELETE` etc) rather than getting curl to choose it for you.

```
echo "how are you" | curl -vvv -d@- http://localhost:8000
* About to connect() to localhost port 8000 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8y zlib/1.2.5
> Host: localhost:8000
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 11
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 11 out of 11 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sun, 03 Aug 2014 13:46:44 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

2) You can specify that you are sending your data in `json` format by using the `Content-type` header. This header can be added in curl using the `-H` option.

3) Yes you can setup a webserver(using `python, nodejs, rails` etc) that can just printout the `http body` once it receives it.

Answer (score 1):

1. `$ curl -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://example.com/posts`
2. `$ curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json"  http://example.com/posts`
3. I prefer use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo